# How to check Balance of a specific account (MetaCoin)

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, ether, javascript

I'm fairly new to programing and solidity, still on the learning curve of things here.... So right now I'm trying to check for the balance in Wei of the account I submit into the text field (Account). How do I achieve this functionality?

[image: Check]

**My html code for this in index.html is**;

```
<h1>Check</h1>
    <br><label for="acctAddress">Account:</label><input type="text" id="acctAddress" placeholder="e.g., 0x93e66d9baea28c17d9fc393b53e3fbdd76899dae"></input>
    <br><br><button id="check" onclick="checkBalance()">Check Balance</button>
    <br>
    <h3>You have <span class="green"><span id="acctBalance"></span> META</span>
    </h3>
```

**The Metacoin Solidity in MetaCoin.sol function is;**

```
function checkBalance(address _account) returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[_account];
    }
```

**The JavaScript function in app.js is**

```
function checkBalance() {


    var acctAddress = document.getElementById("acctAddress").value;
    var check_element = document.getElementById("acctBalance");

    setStatus("Retreving Balance... (please wait)");

    web3.eth.getBalance(acctadd) 

      acctAddress = acctadd;


    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are not mixing these 2 concepts:

- The ether balance of your account, which you retrieve with `web3.eth.getBalance(YOUR_ADDRESS)`.
- The MetaCoin balance stored in the contract, which you retrieve with `contractAddress.checkBalance(YOUR_ADDRESS)`.

So if your case, you want to:

```
function checkBalance() {
    var acctAddress = document.getElementById("acctAddress").value;
    var check_element = document.getElementById("acctBalance");

    setStatus("Retreving Balance... (please wait)");

    MetaCoin.deployed().checkBalance(acctAddress)
        .then(function(balance) {
            console.log(balance.toString(10));
            console.log(balance.toNumber());
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
};
```

Note that Truffle uses [Ether-Pudding](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ether-pudding) so your contract calls return promises.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it to display the balance although it seems to be wrong, I sent 5 to the address 0xcb439bd73060413b5b24227bd2bad7b4263039b6, or could it be a conversion thing?!.  I also managed to add a field that returns the transaction hash but i get an error.                                                                See screen shot here -> [![SS_meta.png](https://s12.postimg.org/xoc6hrl7x/SS_meta.png)](https://postimg.org/image/gb1w2wpwp/)  and The code functions here -> [![bal_tran.png](https://s13.postimg.org/4lq1rvgiv/bal_tran.png)](https://postimg.org/image/zfxaplm5f/)

Comment: Well, of course, you are using `web3.eth.getBalance()`. Read my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I'm doing it using Truffle and the Web3 API :

```
web3.eth.getBalance(address, 'latest', function(err, result) {
    if (err != null) {
        console.error("Error while retrieving the balance for address["+address+"]: "+err);
    }

    var balance = Number(web3.fromWei(result, "ether"));
    console.debug("Balance for address["+address+"]="+balance);
});
```

Please find below the full documentation :

> **web3.eth.getBalance**
>
> web3.eth.getBalance(addressHexString [, defaultBlock] [, callback])
>   Get the balance of an address at a given block.
>
> *Parameters*
>
> String - The address to get the balance of.
>
> Number|String - (optional) If you pass this parameter it will not use the default block set with  web3.eth.defaultBlock.
>
> Function - (optional) If you pass a callback
>   the HTTP request is made asynchronous. See this note for details.

---

EDIT: Full example

**HTML**

```
<label for="amount">Address:</label><input type="text" id="address" placeholder="0x***"></input>
<br><button id="send" onclick="checkBalance()">Check balance</button>
<label for="balance">Balance:</label><input type="text" id="balance" disabled></input>
```

**Javascript**

```
function checkBalance() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    web3.eth.getBalance(address, 'latest', function(err, result) {
        if (err != null) {
            console.error("Error while retrieving the balance for address["+address+"]: "+err);
        }

        var balance = Number(web3.fromWei(result, "ether"));
        console.debug("Balance for address["+address+"]="+balance);

        var balance_element = document.getElementById("balance");
        balance_element.innerHTML = balance.valueOf();
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks @gjeanmart Could you please show me the corresponding html block and solidity block as well?

Comment: Account, balance and transaction are native functions in Ethereum, You don't need a smart contract (in Solidity) to implement a _GetBalance(add)_ function

For the html code. I added a full example which should work

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it to display the balance although it seems to be wrong, I sent 5 to the address 0xcb439bd73060413b5b24227bd2bad7b4263039b6, or could it be a conversion thing?!.  I also managed to add a field that returns the transaction hash but i get an error.                                                                See screen shot here -> [![SS_meta.png](https://s12.postimg.org/xoc6hrl7x/SS_meta.png)](https://postimg.org/image/gb1w2wpwp/)  and The code functions here -> [![bal_tran.png](https://s13.postimg.org/4lq1rvgiv/bal_tran.png)](https://postimg.org/image/zfxaplm5f/)